# Change the Color of a Cell through Google Sheet API: Invalid requests

Tags: java, google-sheets, background-color, google-sheets-api

I want to set the background color of a cell (or group of cell) through Google Sheet API.

I wrote this request, it perfectly works when I write `.setFields("*")`, but I can't do that because this overrides all the previous requests I performed on that cell.

So I specify `.setFields("backgroundColor")` according to the field name as seen in [this document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/cells).
But I get an error:

```
"message" : "Invalid requests[1].repeatCell: Invalid field: background_color",
```

Please note that *backgroundColor* has become *background_color*.

I tried other strings such as *color*, *backgroundcolor*... but none works. I don't know how to do.

```
  Color XgoogleColor = new Color().setRed(1f).setGreen(0f).setBlue(0f); // Color.RED

    return new Request()
            .setRepeatCell(new RepeatCellRequest()
                    .setCell(new CellData()
                            .setUserEnteredFormat(new CellFormat()
                                    .setBackgroundColor(XgoogleColor)
                            )
                    )
                    .setRange(new GridRange()
                            .setSheetId(sheetId)
                            .setStartRowIndex(startRow)
                            .setEndRowIndex(endRow)
                            .setStartColumnIndex(startColumn)
                            .setEndColumnIndex(endColumn)
                    )
                    .setFields("backgroundColor")
            );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- In your script, when `.setFields("*")` is used, the script works.
- You want to update only `backgroundColor`.

In this case, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
.setFields("backgroundColor")
```

#### To:

```
.setFields("userEnteredFormat.backgroundColor")
```

- By this, `backgroundColor` is updated.

#### Reference:

- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)

Comment: Great! Also you clarified how the hierarchy must be preserved. Thank you!

Comment: @Sandor Mezil Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.